# Textures not rendering in AR JS

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I'm having an issue on a project where I'm using Aframe with AR.
Currently the model that I'm using only renders all the textures when you are close but when the distance is higher, some textures don't render and makes it look bad.
Any tips?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dissapearing textures, or "jittering" when moving the objects away is often a result of using a linear depth buffer (in ar.js the objects may seem small, but can be scaled, or far away from the origin point).

Try toggling the usage of a [logaritmic depth buffer](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/renderer.html#logarithmicdepthbuffer):

```
<a-scene renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true" ...
```

Comment: Thanks Piotr. That is one of the first things that I tried and it improved a bit but this issue is still happening.
One thing perhaps good to mention is that at the moment, the scale of the model is in 5000 5000 5000. Not sure exactly why, but it seems that the model was extremly small(which is not on three.js).

Comment: @schumyspain does it occur when using either ar.js markers and nft?

Comment: actually no, I tested with a normal marker and works correctly. Only happens with NFT, which is extremely weird... Any idea why?